# Monitor servers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to monitor three server pages. These three pages contain a simple text (for example it says it's "working fine"). I want to be notified when anything other than this message is displayed, e.g. via email.

I want shell scripting code for displaying the status of the three pages in an html file.

Answer (score 2):

if your pages are proper HTML-pages and you do not want to parse that, you might want to use `lynx` (the old-school text-base browser) for rendering the HTML into plaintext first (using the `--dump` flag):

```
for lnk in http://foo.example.com \
           http://bar.example.com \
           http://stats.example.com/stillrunning.html
do
   lynx --dump "${lnk}" \
   | grep "working fine" \
   || mailx -s "${lnk} failed" you@example.com
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use either `curl` or `wget` along with `bash` to accomplish what you want.

```
$ wget -O- http://example.com | grep "working fine" || mailx -s "Oh NO" you ...
```